# Is there a way to convert PowerPoint theme to LaTeX beamer theme?

Tags: latex, powerpoint, tex, presentation, beamer

I've found quite a few ways to convert the contents of the presentation to .tex file, but that's not what i need.
At job i have to use PowerPoint template, but i'd rather use LaTeX to create presentation itself. Maybe there is an easy way to modify existing beamer theme by adding pictures at the top and the bottom of every slide?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is indeed an easy way to modify existing beamer themes by adding pictures at the top and the bottom of every slide:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=1cm]{example-image-duck}}
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=1cm,page=2]{example-image-duck}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

[image]